# Opencart Shipping Zip Code Check Before Order

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I've an extension installed with opencart which helps customers to know whether their zip code is serviceable by logistics partner. But this is not mandatory. Still customers from these zip codes are ordering and it takes a lot of work for cancellation.

I found oc_zip_code table in mySQL is used. In the checkout page, customer enters Billing details and clicks continue button then Shipping details and continue button. On clicking this button, the system should check the entered zip code with the table and if there is a match it should continue else an error message should be displayed saying, "This zip code is non serviceable"

Or after entering shipping details, it should check automatically and give same error message or success.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Nix. If I was not answering or commenting on this question the system will not notify me even if You point Your comment directly to my `@nickname`... Well, to be honest, it would be helpful if You could post some code, but I see You are completely lost here. I do not know the extension You have installed therefore my advice could not be very accurate. Anyway, in `catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_address.php` and `catalog/controller/checkout/guest_shipping.php` You'll find `validate()` methods - You will have to implement the ZIP verification here so that proper behaviour is preserved.

Comment: Hi @shadyyx... sorry didn't know that... I am relived to just see your comment... this is the extension I used www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9637
This is the developer's demo site where you can check how it works http://ecommerce.aleaitsolutions.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=43

Comment: Sorry to tell You I have no time to research the *third party extension*... In the above comment You have some starting point where You should be able to follow on from... You do the research (mostly of the extension's source code) and You do implement the validation in the above mentioned classes and methods. You are welcome to come back with any concrete problem You may encounter. Good luck & happy programming!

Comment: @shadyyx ok thank you so much for your valuable time and inputs... I'll try my best... thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too difficult to achieve but it requires understanding of OpenCart's controllers and models, some PHP knowledge and MySQL knowledge.

You need to extend your controller and model files.
In the controller/checkout/shipping_method.php I'd add a function named `verifyZipCode($zipcode)` and same function in the model files.

You'd then need to create a new table of valid zip codes in your database and have the controller call the model to query the database and return true or false if the `zipcode` exists.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most payment modules have options to do this for you, for example Stripe is a very good module or PayMill - both have the option to select address and postcode checks before the order goes through.